# Out of memory error when inserting into bytea column

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I am using **.NET Core** and **EF Core** with **NpgSql** driver (PostgreSQL).

I have a simple model:

```
public partial class Attachment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to save large file (~350MB), I get the error `53200 out of memory: Failed on request of size 716624544.`

```
Attachment attachment = new Attachment()
{
    Content = File.ReadAllBytes("largeFile.bin")
};

_dbContext.Attachment.Add(attachment);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Database has enough free memory to be able to store 350MB. What is causing this error?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46675/postgresql-out-of-memory-while-trying-to-a-request-of-500mb

Comment: Just a note to say that this is a PostgreSQL database-side error rather than an Npgsql/EF Core issue - so look for the answer there. I'd also consider changing the way I'm using the database if you find yourself storing binary data that's hundreds of MB in size... You may want to look at PostgreSQL's [large object support](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/largeobjects.html), which also has an [Npgsql support API](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/large-objects) (but outside of EF).